# Cant call a function more than two time using seperate buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm assigning different arguments with the same function, equip, but to different buttons. When i made the third button to call this function, it doesn't work. IS it a limitation with JavaScript? or is there a way to do this?

HTML:

```
<head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/styles.css'>
</head>

<body>

    <p id="para">dud</p>

    <button type="button" onclick="monsterFound();">Test monster</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="d20();">Test a Die 20</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="showChance();">Test Chance</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="d20(); damageAccuracy(damage,dice1,calculateChance());">Test Accuracy</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="equip(loot[1]);">equip weapon1</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="equip(loot[5]);">equip weapon2</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="equip(loot[8]);">equip weapon3</button>

    <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js'></script>
    <script src='main.js'></script>
</body>
```

JS:

```
var loot = [ 'rusty iron dagger', 'rusty iron claymore', 'rusty iron axe', 
'rusty iron hammer', 'rusty iron spear', 'rusty iron warhammer', 'rusty iron 
waraxe', 'rusty iron short sword', 'rusty iron long sword', 'rusty iron 
helmet', 'rusty iron breast-plate', 'rusty iron greaves', 'rusty iron left 
pauldron', 'rusty iron right pauldron'];
// x = 14;
var onHandOut = 0;
var offHandOut = 0;
var onHand = "empty"; // right hand
var offHand = "empty"; // left hand
var damage = 0;
// when you equip a weapon, base damage is set -------------------
alert(onHand);
alert(damage);

function equip(item) {
onHand = item;

if (onHand === "empty") {
    alert("Empty");
    onHandOut = 0.65;
    damage = onHandOut;

} else if (onHand === "rusty iron dagger") {
    onHandOut = 1.25;
    damage = onHandOut;
    alert("Dagger equiped, Damage = " + onHandOut);

} else if (onHand === "rusty iron claymore") {
    onHandOut = 2.25;
    damage = onHandOut;
    alert("claymore equiped, Damage = " + onHandOut);

} else if (onHand === "rusty iron axe") {
    onHandOut = 1.25;
    damage = onHandOut;
    alert("axe equiped, Damage = " + onHandOut);

} else if (onHand === "rusty iron hammer") {
    onHandOut = 1.5;
    damage = onHandOut;
    alert("hammer equiped, Damage = " + onHandOut);

} else if (onHand === "rusty iron spear") {
    onHandOut = 1.75;
    damage = onHandOut;
    alert("spear equiped, Damage = " + onHandOut);

} else if (onHand === "rusty iron warhammer") {
    onHandOut = 2.5;
    damage = onHandOut;
    alert("warhammer equiped, Damage = " + onHandOut);

} else if (onHand === "rusty iron waraxe") {
    onHandOut = 2.25;
    damage = onHandOut;
    alert("waraxe equiped, Damage = " + onHandOut);

} else if (onhand === "rusty iron short sword") {
    onHandOut = 2.25;
    damage = onHandOut;
    alert("short sword equiped, Damage = " + onHandOut);

} else if (onHand === "rusty iron long sword") {
    onHandOut = 2.5;
    damage = onHandOut;
    alert("long sword equiped, Damage = " + onHandOut);

} else if (onhand === "empty") {
    onHandOut = 0.625;
    damage = onHandOut;
    alert("no weapon equiped, Damage = " + onHandOut);

} else {
    // Do nothing!
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it is just a typo on your code (**onhand** instead of **onHand**).

Where you have this line

```
} else if (onhand === "rusty iron short sword") {
```

It should be:

```
} else if (onHand === "rusty iron short sword") {
```

Comment: I fixed the typo, but the third button will still not work :(

Comment: I fixed the typo, but the third button will still not work :( UPDATE*: Worked, thank-you so much :)